# Excel hyperlink to a file-shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, file-shortcut

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains a hyperlink to a (file-)shortcut to another Excel spreadsheet.
The shortcut is meant to easily change the target spreadsheet (roll over new versions for example).
When I click on the hyperlink Excel seems to be broken, it displays the hourglass, doesn't open the second spreadsheet, works partially then finishes by failing.
I use Excel 2016 from Office 365. Is this a known bug ?
Thanks

Comment: Do hyperlinks to other files / locations work? Does the file open correctly if you open it from its folder?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Yes an hyperlink direct to the second excel spreadsheet works (the same spreadsheet the shortcut refers to): Excel opens the spreadsheet fine. Also I made tests using the C: drive to avoid any UNC / path related problems, so the issue occurs with all files in the C: drive. There is no error when I try the hyperlink to the shorcut, just Excel is not responsive for some time (like if it was busy), then you can edit the original spreadsheet, but after some time Excel just hangs .. like if the hyperlink opening was still processing in the background and never completing.

Comment: Indeed in our environment, I tested with all Excel 2010, 2013, 2016 and got the same result for all three

Comment: Try opening both spreadsheets first and then verify link works without issue.  IF it works, then may need to go into security center and enable external links

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and happened to stumble on the solution.  Shortcut files have a hidden file extension, ".lnk" which you'll need to include at the end of the target filename.  That's it!